# Javascript concatenate a function similar to how text can be added

Tags: javascript

In javscript we can do this

```
var text = "the original text";

text+=";Add this on";
```

If a library has a function already defined (e.g)

```
//In the js library
library.somefunction = function() {...};
```

Is there a way to add something on so that I can have two functions run?

```
var myfunction = function() {...};
```

Something like:

```
library.somefunction += myfunction
```

So that both `myfunction()` and the original `library.somefunction()` are both run?

Comment: Do you want the library's function to be changed to run both the original function and your custom function or do you want a new function that runs both?

Comment: I want the library's original function changed to run both

Comment: Could you check the difference http://jsfiddle.net/TLStb/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this kind of code (leave scope empty to use default scope):

```
var createSequence = function(originalFn, newFn, scope) {
    if (!newFn) {
        return originalFn;
    }
    else {
        return function() {
            var result = originalFn.apply(scope || this, arguments);
            newFn.apply(scope || this, arguments);
            return result;
        };
    }
}
```

Then:

```
var sequence = createSequence(library.somefunction, myFunction);
```

Comment: Hi rab, I checked it and it was not passing the scope at originalFn.apply. Fixed that now

Answer (score 0):

I think what you want to create is a [Hook](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hooking) (function) - you want to call `library.somefunction` but add a bit of your own code to run before. If that's the case, you can make your `myfunction` either call or return the library function after it's done with your bit of code.

```
var myfunction = function() {

    // your code
    // ...

    return library.somefunction();
}
```

Comment: I also need to ensure that myfunction() is hooked in when library.somefunction() is called